# Convert overlay effect from psd to UIImage in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, overlay, psd

I have a .psd file with an Overlay effect logo. When I export to png, I get a white logo and can't transfer the effect. Tried to blur in Swift but it doesn't show the same effect. How can I implement the same effect using `Swift`?

> Photoshop Effect:

[image: Photoshop Overlay Effect]

> Logo in iOS Project:

[image: iOS Project]

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [UIVisualEffectView](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIVisualEffectView/index.html) . Also a good tutorial can be found [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/84043/ios-8-visual-effects-tutorial)